# JS/CSS slideshow not working as intended

Tags: javascript, css, slideshow

I'm using this slider here: http://css-tricks.com/examples/FeaturedContentSlider/

When I put it on my website here: http://www.cozinhatur.com/cozinhas/copyofportas.html

The thumbnails below aren't where they should be, and I can't see the whole text. I tried with Firefox (Inspecting Element) but couldn't do anything with it.

P.S.: Well, basically I'm looking for a slideshow like that where I can show some images.

Comment: The problem you are having on your page also seems to exist on the demo page (to a lesser degree).

Comment: "Well, basically I'm looking for a slideshow like that where I can show some images" There are 1000's of slideshows out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you have a generic rule in your stylesheet that is screwing it up

```
.body img {  padding:0; margin:10px auto;}
```

removing that and it works okay, so that means you need to override this in your stylesheet for the slideshow

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
#movers-row {
    margin: -64px 0 0 62px; 
}

.slider-wrap .cross-link {
    margin: 0px auto; 
}
```

below your other CSS styles.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. epascarello nailed it for me.